# How to create a layout and run commands in at tmux launch?

Tags: tmux

I am trying to write a script I can run/source so tmux set a specific layout and run commands. I have some results.

Here is what I've written so far:

```
selectp -t 1
splitw -v -p 15
splitw -h -p 50

selectp -t 1
send-keys 'cd ~/code/octoly' Enter
send-keys 'vim .' Enter

selectp -t 2
send-keys 'cd ~/code/octoly' Enter
send-keys 'drails c' Enter

new-window -d -n server -c ~/code/octoly
selectw -t 2
send-keys 'fd' Enter

splitw -h -p 50
send-keys 'cd ~/code/octoly' Enter
send-keys 'drails s' Enter

selectp -t 1
splitw -v -p 50
send-keys 'cd ~/code/octoly' Enter
send-keys 'be guard' Enter
```

What works more or less is the creation of the second window and the panes. Though the panes does not give me what I want. They are all created in the first window, none are created in the second.

Here is what I run to start tmux:

```
tmux new 'tmux move-window -t 99 \; source-file ~/.tmux/session_octoly'
```

Furthermore, where I'm really lost is that if I run each command by hand one by one, it gives me what I want.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you're using the `-d` flag in `new-window` that does not make the new window the *current window*:

> If -d is given, the session does not make the new window the current window.

However I would probably spin up `tmux` in a different way, using `tmux -f` flag to use an ad-hoc config file that does what you want.
*Please check the commands before running it in you're environment.*

```
# File: ~/.tmux/octoly.conf

# Load default .tmux.conf
source-file ~/.tmux.conf

# setup octoly session
new-session -s octoly -n editor -d -c ~/code/octoly
send-keys 'vim .' Enter

split-window -v -p 15 -c ~/code/octoly
send-keys 'drails c' Enter
split-window -h -p 50 -c ~/code/octoly

# Select vim pane 
select-pane -t 1

# create second window
new-window -n server -c ~/code/octoly
send-keys 'fd' Enter

split-window -h -p 50 -c ~/code/octoly
send-keys 'drails s' Enter

select-pane -t 1
split-window -v -p 50 -c ~/code/octoly
send-keys 'be guard' Enter

# Optional step, reselect window 1 (the one with vim)
select-window -t editor
```

Then you need to launch `tmux` using:

```
tmux -f ~/.tmux/octoly.conf attach
```

Another alternative would be to build a bash script sending the same commands.

**Note**: I've used the `-c` flag to specify the start directory instead of running every time a `cd` command. Given that every command is run in the same folder you can take them out in the `split-window` commands.